# mysql data type decimal(18,6) insert 0.000001 but change 6E-6 why?

Tags: mysql, decimal

i have one question.
please answer for me.

- I made one table.
- I want to insert 0.000001
- But I can't insert this value.
- Why I can't Insert 0.000001?
- I can Insert 1.000001

Why???? I don't understand...

please help me...

---

```
CREATE TABLE `TEST` (
  `VAL` decimal(18,6) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'TEST'
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SELECT * FROM TEST

INSERT TEST(VAL) VALUE(0.000001);
INSERT TEST(VAL) VALUE(1.000001);

SELECT * FROM TEST
```

Comment: it's just another notation for the same number...

Comment: It works fine on SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23d878/1.

Comment: [Scientific notation!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

Comment: Define "can't". Why do you think you "can't"?

Comment: What are you using to *view* the values in the database? Are you using a dedicated mysql client (ex.: phpmyadmin), or do you have a software application that issues queries to the database?

Answer (score 3):

You get the number `0.000001` converted to a *float* at some point, but NOT in MySQL, because the [*decimal*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) data type is a precision one. You most probably have some other point where the value from the *decimal* is is converted to a *float*.

When `0.000001` is put into a *float* data type it will not be stored precisely because [*float*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) is not a precise data type, but an approximated one, and what you get back as an output string representation may be a bit strange and is entirely up to the programming language and/or environment. For small numbers you sometimes get the `E` notation, at other times you may end up with a value just a bit different from what you would expect (ex.: `7.999998` instead of `8`).

Comment: Some program's choice to render in scientific notation doesn't really have anything to do with floating-point precision limitations, though there's nothing strictly incorrect about this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The insertion works just fine, and if you run those statements in the MySQL client you'll see the output you expect:

```
VAL
1.000001
0.000001
```

More than likely you are using some program that you haven't shown us, in some programming language that you haven't mentioned, which is choosing to render the values using scientific notation to a lower degree of precision than that used by the database. Usually you can request that it instead render the value using a fixed format.

For example, in C++:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
   const float x = 0.000001;
   std::cout << x << '\n';
   std::cout << std::fixed << x << '\n';
}

// Output:
//  
//  1e-06
//  0.000001
```

Comment: thanks... i understood.. but i can't use this code.. because I need use to only mysql.. but this code will help some other user...

Comment: @user2461850: I said "for example", not "use this code". I was demonstrating that you have _no problem_ here and that, if you're using "only MySQL" then your problem simply does not exist without some crucial detail that you've omitted.